# 32 bit division in assembly language

Tags: assembly

I'm learning assembly language programming in my college course (80386 programming). Currently, I'm learning the ins and outs of 32 bit division using the EDX and EAX registers to store the remainder and quotient respectively. I want to know, why do I not get the correct output when I don't include

```
mov edx, 00000000h
```

in my program. The program either doesn't run or gives the wrong output.

Relevant source code:

```
mov edx, 00000000h
mov eax, 1234567Ah
div 11111111h ; now EDX=remainder, EAX=quotient
```

I will post the full code if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `DIV` with a 32-bit operand, it will divide the 64-bit value in `EDX:EAX` (high DWORD in `EDX`, low DWORD in `EAX`) by the operand and put the quotient in `EAX` and the remainder in `EDX`.

Therefore you should clear `EDX` prior to the division if the value you want to divide is 32 bits (fits in `EAX` alone). Failure to do so will result in incorrect results, or a division overflow if the quotient doesn't fit in `EAX`.

Comment: Oh of course, division will divide EDX:EAX, that slipped my mind! Thank you for the answer, my question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

32-bit div actually divides edx:eax by the specified value.  If edx has random garbage in it, you'll get garbage results.  There's no option to divided JUST with eax...