# x86 Assembly (NASM): Floating Point Exception, not dividing by 0?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm trying to compute the expression `A * B + ( A + B ) / ( A - B )`, where A and B are integers input by the user. I'm using the ALong32 library on a linux kernel.

```
%include "along32.inc"

section .data
msg1    db      'Enter A: ', 0
msg2    db      'Enter B: ', 0
msg3    db      'Result: ' , 0
err     db      'Error: cannot divide by 0', 0
A       resb    4
B       resb    4

section .text

global main

main:
    mov     edx,    msg1
    call    WriteString
    call    ReadInt
    mov     [A],    eax  ; move the input into A

    mov     edx,    msg2
    call    WriteString
    call    ReadInt      ; move the next number into eax

    cmp     eax,    [A]  ; compare A and eax (B)

    je      error        ; if A and B are equal, error

    mov     [B],    eax  ; move eax into B 

    mov     eax,    [A]
    add     eax,    [B]
    mov     ebx,    eax ; ebx = A + B

    mov     eax,    [A]
    sub     eax,    [B] ; eax = A - B

    div     ebx        

    mov     ebx,    eax ; ebx = (A + B) / (A - B)

    mov     ecx,    [B]
    mov     eax,    [A]
    mul     ecx        
    mov     ecx,    eax ; ecx = A * B

    add     eax,    ecx ; eax = A * B + (A + B) / (A - B)

    mov     edx,    msg3
    call    WriteString
    call    WriteInt

    jmp end

error:
    mov     edx,    err
    call    WriteString
    jmp end

end:
    mov     eax,    1
    int     0x80
```

I feel like I've commented what I'm doing pretty well, but I'll explain what I'm doing more in depth if that's needed.

When I run this code, after I input both numbers, I get a `floating point exception`, and the program exits.

Why is this happening? I check for division by 0.

Comment: You forgot to read the instruction set reference page for DIV and you forgot to search stackoverflow.

Comment: I looked at both of those! All of the other SO questions on this related to division by 0, which I check for. @Jester

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21381576/547981) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231784/why-div-edx-in-masm-always-generates-processor-exception) for example.

Comment: I don't understand those answers and how they relate to my question! I'm using EAX for the quotient, and I'm not even editing edx. Unless I need to clear it before I use it? @Jester

Comment: Which part is confusing? `DIV` as you use it will use `edx` for the top 32 bits of the dividend and you don't set it up. TL;DR: you need to zero `edx` before the `DIV`.

Comment: Ok, thank you! @Jester

Comment: Also note that the CPU's "divide error" exception is used for overflows in integer divisions (which includes division by zero). When EDX:EAX contains (e.g.) 0x1234567800000004 and you divide by 4 the result (quotient) doesn't fit in EAX and you get a "divide error" exception. I also assume the kernel sees this exception and sends a "math error" signal to your process, and someone somewhere decided (for no sane reason) that "math error" must mean floating point(!).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see 2 problems with your program.

- The `div ebx` instruction uses EDX:EAX as the dividend and you fail to set it up. Just insert an `xor edx,edx`

  ```
  xor   edx, edx ; <--------------------------------- Add this !
  div   ebx        
  mov   ebx, eax ; ebx = (A + B) / (A - B)
  ```
- After the division you store the quotient in EBX but you never pick it up again to display the result!

  ```
  mov   ecx, [B]
  mov   eax, [A]
  mul   ecx
  mov   ecx, eax ; ecx = A * B
  mov   eax, ebx ; <--------------------------------- Add this !
  add   eax, ecx ; eax = A * B + (A + B) / (A - B)
  ```

The 2nd issue can be solved in a shorter way:

```
mov   ecx, [B]
mov   eax, [A]
mul   ecx
add   eax, ebx ; eax = A * B + (A + B) / (A - B)
```

---

**EDIT** (late catch, sorry)

> I check for division by 0.
>
> A * B + ( A + B ) / ( A - B )

You've based your check on the divider being `(A - B)` and thus exit if `A` is equal to `B`.
Correct, but the program code erroneously calculates `(A - B) / (A + B)` and so is using `(A + B)` as the divider!

This is my version of calculating `A * B + ( A + B ) / ( A - B )`:

```
mov     ebx, [A]
sub     ebx, [B]    ; EBX = (A - B)
jz      error       ; Guard against division by zero!

mov     eax, [A]
add     eax, [B]    ; EAX = (A + B)

xor     edx, edx    ; EDX:EAX = (A + B)
div     ebx         ; EAX = (A + B) / (A - B)

mov     ebx, [A]
imul    ebx, [B]    ; EBX = A * B

add     eax, ebx    ; EAX = A * B + (A + B) / (A - B)
```